# IF, MATCH, OR Formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

I've tried the following formulas:

```
=IF(OR(MATCH(B2;Visitors!$B:$B;0);MATCH(B2;Owners!$B:$B;0));TRUE;FALSE)
=IF(MATCH(B2;Visitors!$B:$B;0);TRUE;MATCH(B2;Owners!$B:$B;0))
=IF(MATCH(B7;Visitors!$B:$B;0);TRUE;IF(NOT(MATCH(B7;Visitors!$B:$B;0));MATCH(B7;Owners!$B:$B;0);FALSE))
```

But these do not work.

I want it to match B2 with Visitors!$B:$B, and if it doesn't match I want it to match B2 with Owners!$B:$B.

If both do not match the result should be #N/A, else TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(B2;Visitors!$B:$B;0)>0;IFERROR(MATCH(B2;Owners!$B:$B;0)>0;"#N/A"))
```